# How to include the 2 query data into single result?

Tags: php, mysql

I had 2 queries like this

Query 1

```
        $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('transaction_log');
    $this->db->join('crs_hotel_booking_details', 'transaction_log.app_reference = crs_hotel_booking_details.app_reference');
    $this->db->join('crs_hotel_supplier_details', 'crs_hotel_booking_details.hotel_id = crs_hotel_supplier_details.hotel_id');
    $this->db->join('crs_supplier_login', 'crs_supplier_login.supplier_id = crs_hotel_supplier_details.supplier_id');
    $this->db->where('crs_supplier_login.supplier_id',$this->entity_user_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
```

Query 2

```
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('transaction_log');
    $this->db->join('service_booking_details', 'transaction_log.app_reference = service_booking_details.app_reference');
    $this->db->join('crs_service_supplier_details', 'service_booking_details.service_apartment_id = crs_service_supplier_details.service_apartment_id');
    $this->db->join('crs_supplier_login', 'crs_supplier_login.supplier_id = crs_service_supplier_details.supplier_id');
    $this->db->where('crs_supplier_login.supplier_id',$this->entity_user_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
```

I got the values in both queries. Please tell me how add this two queries

Comment: Add them to what?

Comment: What You Exactly Want.? 2 Query In Single Query OR To Add results in?

Comment: you need to loop it and add to another array

Comment: Nana i tried 2 query into single but i facing error. so i tried getting 2 queries values and passed as a single value. if its is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just as,

```
array_merge($query1->result_array(), $query2->result_array());
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL has the [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) clause which returns a single resultset from two or more SELECT statements.